# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: work.methods.workCount is not a function

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, dapps, javascript

**Describe the bug**
I am trying to call the public variable "workCount" from a smart contract using web3

**Steps to reproduce**:

```
const work = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI,Address)

const workCount = await work.methods.workCount().call()
```

**Expected behavior**

I am expecting these two lines of code to return the value of `workCount`

**Actual behavior:**

Once I run the application I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: work.methods.workCount is not a function
```

if I change the code to the following:

```
const workCount = await work.methods.workCount.call()
```

then this error is shows up:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

**Contract Code:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract workReg {
  uint public workCount = 0;

  struct Work {
    uint id;
    string authorName;
    string workType; 
    string description;
    uint amount;
  }

  mapping(uint => Work) public works;

  constructor() public {
    createWork("Heba","Book", "IP blockchain book", 100);
  }

  function createWork(string memory _authorName, string memory _workType, string memory _description, uint  _amount ) public {
    workCount ++;
    works[workCount] = Work(workCount, _authorName,_workType, _description, _amount);
  }

 function getID() view public returns(uint){
    
    return  works[workCount].id;
}


 function getworkType() view public returns(string memory){
    
    return  works[workCount].workType;
} 


 function getdescription() view public returns(string memory){
    
    return  works[workCount].description;
} 

function getAmount() view public returns(uint){
    
    return  works[workCount].amount;
}

}
```

Comment: What's the contract code? What's solidity version? What's web3 version? From the error message either the ABI is wrong, wrong web3 version, workCount is not public, or something else.

Comment: you can fine contract code on the question. The following are packages versions:
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.7.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.2",
"solc": "^0.8.1",
"uuid": "^8.3.2",
"uuidv4": "^6.2.6",
"web-vitals": "^1.1.0",
"web3": "^1.3.4"

Comment: Everything appears to be right. How is web3 instantiated? I repeat again from the error message it appears that ABI or address is wrong. Can you regenerate the ABI, check the address is correct and try again?

Comment: I checked the address it is the same as the one I am using in web3. How can I create the ABI again?

Comment: Thank you @Ismael I copied the ABI again to react and it works fine.

Comment: Great that you fixed the problem. If you use truffle it generates the ABI inside a json file with the contract name in the build/ directory. Sorry, I don't remember exactly but there's a section in that file that contains the ABI.

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the comments on OP's question, it becomes clear that there was an issue with the ABI the OP was originally using (h/t @Ismael) - perhaps it was copy pasted incompletely, or maybe there was some file corruption. By regenerating the ABI, the code worked as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment. I would like to ask what does OP stands for?

Comment: OP = Original Poster. It's a shorthand way of saying "that person who asked the question" that you'll see a lot on the platform.